# How can I add labels to a distance matrix used to make a dendrogram and have the labels also show on the dendrogram

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy

I have a distance matrix:

```
array('d', [188.61516889752, 226.68716730362135, 188.96015266132167])
```

I would like to add labels to the matrix before performing hierarchical cluster using scipy.

I produce a UPGMA dendrogram from the distance matrix using:

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import average, fcluster
#from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

outDND=average(distanceMatrix)
```

I have tried adding the labels to the dendrogram using:

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import average, fcluster
#from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

outDND=average(distanceMatrix, labels=['A','B','C'])
```

But that does not work.  I get the error:

```
TypeError: average() got an unexpected keyword argument 'labels'
```

How can I add labels to 'distanceMatrix' and have them carry through to outDND?

Comment: Please expand on "does not work" - Do you get an error? Are there labels other than what you expect? No labels at all?

Comment: I get the error: TypeError: average() got an unexpected keyword argument 'labels'

Comment: The immediate TypeError is because you can't use the "labels" keyword in a call to that `average()` function. See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.average.html Still looking for options in putting labels on the dendrogram

Comment: Possible duplicate / reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35873273/display-cluster-labels-for-a-scipy-dendrogram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a couple steps between "create the distance matrix" and "create the dendrogram".

See [this other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35873273/display-cluster-labels-for-a-scipy-dendrogram) for several worked examples.

In general, `scipy` and the underlying `numpy` tend not to include labels in their data structures. (Unlike, say `pandas`, which *does* track labels.). That means you're responsible for keeping separate lists of labels and figuring out the correct order & references.

The steps you'll need are:

- Compute the distance matrix (which you've done, [although you should drop the unrecognized "labels" parameter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.average.html))
- Use the [scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage() function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html#scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage) to find hierarchies using the just-computed distance matrix.
- Display the resulting linkages using [scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram.html).  This is the step at which you'll be able to insert your labels using the "labels" argument.

Comment: Bummer, I was hoping there was a built-in parameter to associate the labels with their index.  Thank you for being so thorough in your response.  One note though; it is not necessary to use 'scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage()' because 'outDND=average(distanceMatrix)' performs UPGMA hierarchical clustering on a pre-computed distance matrix.